# Windows Azure rewrite rules for Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, iis, azure, frameworks, url-rewriting

Currently I have the following htaccess on my apache:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

My application uses Zend Framework as MVC framework and currently my htaccess is in my public folder.

On MS Azure I created a website in IIS and placed a web.config file in my root with the following config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="TransferToPublic-StaticContent" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="*images*" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="*css*" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="*js*" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="*bootstrap*" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="*upload*" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="*theme*" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="*img*" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^.*$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public/index.php" />
                </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

The problem is that now I cannot access pages that have the following path /public/index or /public/test

What am I doing wrong?  Is there something missing in the config?  What is the recommended config for Zend Framework on IIS?

thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a little old, but if you did not solve your problem, here's the answer on how to configure Zend Framework on IIS.

[Zend Documentation for IIS](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/de/project-structure.rewrite.html#project-structure.rewrite.iis)

But maybe your problem is also setting the document root. You shouldn't point your rewrite to "public/index.php" instead just "index.php" and then set the correct document root.

Here's my question answered for Azure Websites: [Azure Websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24505574/set-document-root-in-zend-framework-1-12-x-application-in-azure-web-sites)
Still waiting for an answer on Azure Cloud Services: [Azure Cloud Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24821599/set-document-root-in-zend-framework-1-12-x-application-in-azure-cloud-service?lq=1)

Azure VM should be self explanatory as you configure IIS on your own.