# Set document root in Zend Framework 1.12.x application in Azure Web Sites

Tags: zend-framework, iis, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a problem setting the document root for a Zend Framework application that I want to run in Azure.

Now I'm testing Web Sites, Cloud Service and VM's to deploy my work.

Deploying with Webmatrix works fine, but I need to set the document root of IIS to a subfolder.

```
- application
- htdocs => Webroot with Web.config
- libs
```

How do I set this? With a second Web.config outside of htdocs Redirecting inside? Tried that, but IIS doesn't seem to like it (500err).

The only thing I found was building a WEBSITE_PRIVATE_EXTENSIONS to change the ApplicationHost.config: [Azure PHP Documentation](http://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/documentation/articles/web-sites-transform-extend/)

This seems to be which seems to be overly complicated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Portal and open the CONFIGURE tab for your site
2. Scroll all the way to the bottom
   [image]
3. Change `site\wwwroot` to point wherever you want to